# I need help figuring out the best way to query this in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having a problem coming up with a query that would work for these models. I have three models that are connected.

An Organization has many Users, and Users have many StatusEntries

Basically this means I could do

```
Organization.find(1).users.find(1).status_entries
```

And have a list of status_entries returned to me.

The problem is I am trying to find a list of status_entries for a specific Organization. I am having trouble coming up with a way of doing this that is not overly complicated and is elegant. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an organization's status_entries for a one user, or for all users?

Comment: All users, so the entries for all of the users of a specific organization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's a case for a have_many :through association :

```
class Organization
  has_many :users
  has_many :status_entries, :through => :users
end
```

then you can do :

```
Organization.find(1).status_entries
```

Comment: Awesome response, it did not even occur to me to do that. Cuts out like 15 lines of cruft from different places. Thank you!